# Why some elements in a list return None for value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash

I have a flower definition list that has each flower and its meaning in a list. For some reason, whenever I look for 'rose' or 'wisteria', it says they are NOT in the list. Basically, it returns a string I defined whenever the flower searched for is not in the list.

I'm using a hash map.

If I change 'rose' to 'roses', it works fine for that flower. Why is that? I thought it was maybe because the word rose was too short, which doesn't make any sense, but I was trying to investigate all possibilities. 'wisteria' is not short and it has the same output.

I have included the code for linked_list.py and blossom_lib.py in this code block for easier studying.

```
from linked_list import Node, LinkedList
from blossom_lib import flower_definitions

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next_node = None

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_next_node(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next_node(self, next_node):
        self.next_node = next_node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head_node=None):
        self.head_node = head_node

    def insert(self, new_node):
        current_node = self.head_node

        if not current_node:
            self.head_node = new_node

        while (current_node):
            next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
            if not next_node:
                current_node.set_next_node(new_node)
            current_node = next_node

    def __iter__(self):
        current_node = self.head_node
        while (current_node):
            yield current_node.get_value()
            current_node = current_node.get_next_node()

class HashMap:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.array_size = size
        self.array = [LinkedList() for i in range(self.array_size)]

    def hash(self, key):
        key_bytes = key.encode()
        hash_code = sum(key_bytes)
        return hash_code

    def compressor(self, hash_code):
        return hash_code % self.array_size

    def assign(self, key, value):
        hash_code = self.hash(key)
        array_index = self.compressor(hash_code)
        payload = Node([key, value])
        list_at_array = self.array[array_index]

        for list in list_at_array:
            if list[0] == key:
                list[1] = value

        list_at_array.insert(payload)

    def retrieve(self, key):
        hash_code = self.hash(key)
        array_index = self.compressor(hash_code)
        list_at_index = self.array[array_index]

        for list in list_at_index:
            if list[0] == key:
                return "\n" + list[0] + " means " + list[1]
            else:
                return "\n" + key + " not found in list!"

flower_definitions = [['begonia', 'cautiousness'], ['chrysanthemum', 'cheerfulness'], ['carnation', 'memories'],
                      ['daisy', 'innocence'], ['hyacinth', 'playfulness'], ['lavender', 'devotion'],
                      ['magnolia', 'dignity'], ['morning glory', 'unrequited love'], ['periwinkle', 'new friendship'],
                      ['poppy', 'rest'], ['roses', 'love'], ['snapdragon', 'grace'], ['sunflower', 'longevity'],
                      ['wisteria', 'good luck']]

blossom = HashMap(len(flower_definitions))

for flower in flower_definitions:
    blossom.assign(flower[0], flower[1])
    print(flower[0])

print(str(blossom.retrieve('wisteria')))
```

Comment: If the item being searched for wasn't the first element in its list, `HashMap.retrieve()` will return "not found" immediately instead of checking the other elements.

Comment: You need to move the else and return one level less of indent.

Comment: @jasonharper if this were true, none of the other flowers would return their proper value either. 'periwinkle' isn't first, yet it returns just fine. As well as 'sunflower'. I am searching they key, if I remove else and return one less level, it would return all flowers and their definition, defeating the purpose of the search for the key.

Comment: I'm talking about the individual LinkedLists in your HashMap, not the overall list of flowers.  With the way you're sizing `self.array`, the average length of the lists is one, so most of the flowers are likely to be the only thing in their list and therefore can be found.

Comment: @jasonharper so what would you change in order to see if what you're saying is the issue will be resolved?

Comment: @DanD, that would defeat the purpose of searching for a key and checking to see if the key matches.

Comment: Do what @DanD said, or eliminate the `else:` line completely and unindent the "not found" line by two levels.  Basically, that `for` loop has to be able to run to completion, rather than always returning on the first iteration.

Comment: @DanD. Bro! I finally understood what you meant. Thanks for the speedy answer and I also understand more about control flow.